# Using less in a polymer-dart application

Tags: css, dart, less, dart-polymer

I've never used LESS before, but seeing as there is a transformer for it available in Dart, I've decided to throw it in the mix.

pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  less_dart: any
transformers:
- less_dart:
    entry_point: web/alm.less
```

I've removed the styles.css entry in my index.html and replaced it with alm.less:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="alm.less">
```

Inside alm.less, if I do:

```
* /deep/ core-toolbar .core-selected {
  background-color: #FF5252;
  color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

I can see the colour changing, but if I do this:

```
@darkPrimaryColor:   #E64A19;

* /deep/ core-toolbar .core-selected {
  background-color: @darkPrimaryColor;
  color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

that `background-color` switches back to its default and ignores my `@darkPrimaryColor;`

Looking at the output of `pub build`, it places that LESS file directly into `index.html` without parsing the `@darkPrimaryColor;`

According to https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/less_dart, I'm supposed to import two dart files, they don't say where exactly, so I've included them in my `main-app.dart`:

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:less_dart/less.dart';
import 'package:less_dart/transformer.dart'; 

@CustomTag('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {
    ...
}
```

Main App is loaded as follows in index.html:

```
<body unresolved>
  <main-app class="default"></main-app>
  <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
</body>
```

Those two includes causes the following errors, so I've removed them again:

```
The requested built-in library is not available on Dartium.'package:less_dart/less.dart': error: line 4 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'dart:io';
^: package:less_dart/less.dart
```

**Update**:

So removing the .pub and doing pub get and pub cache repair doesn't do much different.
I've done a pub serve from the command line to see what it outputs:

```
pub serve
Loading source assets... 
Loading polymer and less_dart transformers... 
Serving falm web on http://localhost:8080
[Info from less-dart] command: lessc --no-color web/alm.less > web/alm.css
[Info from less-dart] lessc transformation completed in 0.0s

[Warning from ImportInliner on falm|web/index.html]:
line 28, column 3 of web/index.html: Failed to inline stylesheet: Could not find asset falm|web/alm.css.
null. See http://goo.gl/5HPeuP#polymer_26 for details.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="alm.css">
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Update**

For the record, I'm using dart sdk 1.8.3 and OSX 10.10.1 Yosemite, don't know if this will help.

**Update**

Got it working, pretty neat plugin once it's working!

So inside my transformers I had to move less_dart to be the first transformer, otherwise the polymer transformer is trying to pickup alm.css which has not been generated yet.
I was also missing "build_mode: dart"

```
dependencies:
  ...
  less_dart: ">=0.1.3 <0.2.0"
transformers:
- less_dart:
    entry_point: web/alm.less
    build_mode: dart
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/index.html
- ...
```

Comment: Why did you replace `<link rel="stylesheet" href="alm.css">` with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="alm.less">`? There are different `less` transformers, which one are you using? Does your `.gitignore` file exclude the generated CSS files?

Comment: @Günter, as I said, I'm new to less. Which transformer should I be using? Should that alm.less be alm.css? If I do that, it says it can't find alm.css.
Harry, I've updated the question, there's no mention of including less.js, my understanding is that the transformer in pubspec.yaml will take care of that.

Comment: I don't use LESS and therefore don't know which one you should use but it would be helpful to know which one you are actually using so I can look up the readme and check the instructions (for example if it states to import `*.less` instead of `*.css`).

Comment: The error message you added at the end indicates that you didn't run `pub get` or `pub upgrade` after you added the `less_dart` dependency. If you actually did then delete the `.pub` directory and run `pub cache repair`. Sorry, your `pubspec.yaml` shows which transformer you are using (just got out of bed ... ;-) ).

Comment: This is the one I've included: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/less_dart

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to add `import 'package:less_dart/less.dart';
import 'package:less_dart/transformer.dart';`. These imports are form the section `How to use in other programs` and I assume this is when you wan't to invoke the CSS generation from your your own code **instead** of by the transformer and I'm pretty sure you don't want that.

Comment: Does the file `alm.css` exist in the `web` directory (after you launch your web app)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jan, thanks to try less_dart.

less_dart is a compiler/transformer in the server side. It reads your web/alm.less file and generates web/alm.css.

So, your html file must declare:   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="alm.css">`

(For use href="alm.less" you would need the original javascript implementation (see http://lesscss.org), which support browser transformation).

Your next question: Where is the alm.css file generated?

By default, the transformer use the option: 'build_mode: less'. It reads web/alm.less and writes alm.css in the same directory: web/alm.css.

I suppose your browser is using 'build/web/index.html', so, you need the alm.css in the same directory. For that you need the transformer option: 'build_mode: dart'.

```
dependencies:
  less_dart: any
transformers:
- less_dart:
    entry_point: web/alm.less
    build_mode: dart
```

The less_dart package has two components:

- less compiler (less.dart)
- less transformer (transformer.dart)

The compiler could be used directly throw the command line (lessc is in the bin directory):

```
pub run lessc web/alm.less web/alm.css
```

Or in your Dart program:

```
    import 'package:less_dart/less.dart';
...
    List<String> args = [];
    Less less = new Less();
    args.add('-no-color');
    args.add('file.less');
    args.add('file.css');
    less.transform(args);
```

As Resumen, you must add `build_mode: dart` to the transformer configuration and search `build/web/alm.css`

Comment: I think this should be added to the `pub-build and pub-serve usage` section in the `README.md` file?

Comment: Thanks Adalberto, looks like I'm missing the "build_mode: dart" in my transformer, probably why my less file is not being compiled to CSS.
Will update my pubscpec.yaml later today and get back you.

Comment: "build_mode: dart" includes less in the dart building transformer's pipe. It takes the input from the transformer pipe process and delivers the result to the transformer pipe for additional transformations, before write to file. So you can chain transformers.

Comment: It's working beautifully, thanks Adalberto! I've updated my question to include the working code snippets.

Comment: less_dart has been updated to 0.1.4 to use `build_mode: dart` as default, and simplify the configuration, working more in line with Dart transformers philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

- I'm pretty sure you don't need to add

```dart
import 'package:less_dart/less.dart';
import 'package:less_dart/transformer.dart';
```

when you use the transformer. This is for situations where you want to invoke the CSS generation from your own Dart code (when you don't use the transformer).

- I'm also pretty sure you need to import the `alm.css` file not the `alm.less` file.
- Check that you don't exclude `css` files in your `.gitignore` file (see http://dartbug.com/20110)
- Check that your `packages` directory contains the `less_dart` symlink.
- Delete the `.pub` directory and run `pub cache repair` to remove potentially stale cache and repair the package cache.

Comment: Stil half-asleep here as well :-) I'm including the alm.css file now, but it's unable to find it, probably have an incorrect path, will dig deeper there, not sure what the path should be (see updated question). Those .dart imports I've removed as they cause errors in any case.
.gitignore looks fine, packes does have the less_dart simlink - that's the first thing I checked, deleting .pub and doing pub cache repair was the second thing I did after checking that it's in the packges directory.

Comment: I don't actually see an alm.css file anywhere in the build directory or in web ... interesting

Comment: Let me drop a mail to the authors of the dart_less plugin or log a bug, maybe they have a better idea ...